# How to cut image by top 30% in Unix?

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to cut 30% from the top of the image. 
I know the thread [How to cut a really large raster image into smaller chunks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232354/how-to-cut-a-really-large-raster-image-into-smaller-chunks) but there is no successful approach because I cannot find a distance measure of `convert` from zero to the *end*, only by absolute value dimensions.
Pseudocode

```
convert -crop-y -units-percentage 0x30 heart.png
```

Fig. 1 Input figure

[image]

I can do the task with LaTeX's `adjustbox` but the output in the pdf file is not really end result but a presentation of it. So copying the image from the pdf document yields the original image. 
So this approach failed.

Comment: You could use imagemagick's `identify` to see how large the image is.

Comment: The general approach is to insert the value needed on the command line using `$(command)`.  You then just need to write a command line that can calculate the value needed.  Here you would ask convert to describe the image and pipe it to awk where you can match the value you need and do the necessary calculation and print out the result.

Comment: Your pseudocode is confusing, because reflexively I want to try it to see what's wrong with the result that it produces.  If it's not contributing to the question, I recommend removing it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can [crop a percentage of your image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_percent) though in this case, to avoid running additional commands to get the image height and width (in order to calculate crop offset which by default is relative to top-left corner) you'll also have to [crop relative to gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_gravity) (so that your crop offset position is relative to the bottom-left corner of the image):

```
convert -gravity SouthWest -crop 100x70%x+0+0 infile.jpg outfile.jpg
```

Comment: Confirmed, this approach works! - - You can reverse this approach etc by `NorthWest` to cut from bottom. Great!

Answer (score 5):

The command should be:

```
convert heart.png -gravity south -crop 100x70% +repage heart-out.png
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  I misunderstand the question , try my edit please

Comment: Your new approach cuts by absolute units, not by percentages. Now, the correct cut direction from the top.